# Why doesn't the initial value of use immer change?

Tags: reactjs, immer.js

```js
//PaginationContainer.js
function PaginationContainer(props) {
  const { data = {} } = props;
  const {
    endPage = 5,
    currentPage = 1,
    nextPage = 6,
    prevPage = null,
    pagePerCount = 10,
    pageBlock = 5,
    totalData = 0,
  } = data;

  const PageState = {
    currentPage: currentPage || 1,
    pageNumbers: [],
    totalPage: 0,
  };
  const [values, setValues] = useImmer(PageState);
  console.log("state", PageState);<-every time change!
  console.log("values", values);<- previous value....:(

  ....
}
```

```
console.log 
state
    {currentPage: '1', pageNumbers: Array(0), totalPage: 0}

console.log 
values {currentPage: '8', pageNumbers: Array(10), totalPage: 16}
```

Hello?
I always put new values ​​as props in the container to the pagination controller.
However, the initial value of useInmmer does not change.
Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question or what you're expecting to happen. The whole purpose of Immer is to allow state mutative syntax while not actually mutating state, so I would never expect the initial state to be updated from a state change.

Answer (score 0):

you can use usEffect hook, to ensure values updated with latest changes, then setValues inside it

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    setValues(PageState);
  },[PageState, PageState.currentPage])
```